# How to use slice to exclude rows and columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["AA", "BB"]])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["X", "Y"], ["XX", "YY"]])

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],
                   [5,6,7,8],
                   [9,10,11,12],
                   [13,14,15,16]], index = index, columns = columns)
```

and slice

```
toSkip = ((slice(None), slice(None)), (["X"], slice(None)))
```

I know that I can write `df.loc[slice]` to get the subset of `DataFrame` which corresponds to this slice. But how can I do the opposite so get the difference between original `df` and the one obtained with that slice?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How to invert slicing

To get the idea let's make it more complicated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B", "C"], ["AA", "BB", "CC"]])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["X", "Y", "Z"], ["XX", "YY", "ZZ"]])
data = (
    np
    .arange(len(index) * len(columns))
    .reshape(len(index), len(columns))
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns)
```

Let's say I want to process all the data except the inner square `(B,Y)`.

[image: data]

I can get the square by slicing. To get others I'm gonna use a boolean mask:

```
mask = pd.DataFrame(True, index, columns)
toSkip = ((['B'], slice(None)), (['Y'], slice(None)))
mask.loc[toSkip] = False
```

[image: mask]

Now I can transform others by windowing with `mask`:

```
# just for illustration purposes
# let's invert the sign of numbers
df[mask] *= -1
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is what OP wants but +1 for the effort and nice description ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `slice` is a Series with boolean values, then logical negation operator `~` will give the opposite of the condition. So,

```
df[~slice]
```

will return rows that doesn't satisfy the condition `slice`

Comment: it doesn't work for my `toSkip` slice

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is you want, you can `drop` the index and columns of `toSkip` dataframe

```py
toSkip = ((slice(None), slice(None)), (["X"], slice(None)))

tmp = df.loc[toSkip]
out = df.drop(index=tmp.index, columns=tmp.columns)
```

```
print(out)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Y, XX), (Y, YY)]
Index: []
```